# Proving that something diverges to infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

So I'm trying to prove that the sum of 1/(2k+1) diverges to infinity. I thought about doing a comparison test with the harmonic series 1/k and multiplying the harmonic series by (1/3) so it is (1/3k). Am I allowed to do this? I mean it makes sense since the harmonic series would still diverge and then I can show that 
1 + 1/5 + 1/7 ... > 1/3 + 1/6 + 1/9 ...  By > I mean that each corresponding term is larger than the other. In other words 1> 1/3, 1/5> 1/6, etc since both sums should add up to infinity. Is this totally off base or does my logic not break any rules. Thanks.

Comment: Your logic is fine since $1/3\cdot\infty=\infty$

Comment: Yes, looks like you have it.

Comment: Small detail: the first term of $1/(2k+1)$ should be $1/3$, not $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, proof of divergence by finding a lower bound is perfectly ok.

You have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\to \infty$$
$$\frac13\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\to \infty$$
And finally
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{3k}\to\infty$$

Comment: (It might be preferable to replace $\infty$ by $n$, say, with the notation you're using.)

Comment: You are right, fixed. I wanted to avoid the lengthy notation with limits, given that we all know what is meant here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and for making this change).